# How to resize a pie chart to keep the data legible?

Tags: r, pie-chart

My pie chart is functioning as expected, but I can't figure out how to resize it to show the data better. Below is my chart:

[image]

And the code that I'm using to plot the pie chart

```
    #plot the pie chart
pie(death_sums_df$Deaths.Sum, labels = paste(round(death_sums_df$Percentage, digits=2), '%'), main="Pie Chart of Categories", col = rainbow(length(death_sums_df$Deaths.Sum)))
legend("topleft", death_sums_df$Age.Group, cex = 0.5,
       fill = rainbow(length(death_sums_df$Deaths.Sum)))
```

Comment: your categories are naturally ordered so consider using a bar graph instead

Comment: unfortunately that's not an option for my assignment :(

Comment: Some of the pie slices are extremely small and will overlap no matter what. Can you combine some of the categories together?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot but my professor said it was fine since there are so many!